# Can't get single character in string

Tags: c, string

I'm a real newbie in C programming, I've read a lot about pointers but it seems i'm still confusing myself.

I'm trying to get a single character from a string sucessively, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char input[128];
    char *ch;

    scanf("%s", &input);

    for (ch = input; *ch; ch++) {
        printf("%s\n", ch);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

If I enter "hello" i get the following output:

```
 hello
 ello
 llo
 lo
 o
```

I have tried `printf("%s\n", &ch[0]);`, but still the same thing.

Any help with this would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are still printing a string and incrementing its starting position.

```
printf("%c\n", *ch);
```

Comment: Thank you, I though `printf` needed the pointer and not the value itself, and totally forgot about correctly formating.